# How to reset password for Dell PowerConnect 2708?

Tags: switch, password-reset, dell-powerconnect

I do as the user manual says and press "Managed Mode" button to get into unmanaged mode and then press "Managed Mode" button again for managed mode. This should reset the device to factory defaults and username "Admin" with no password.

However, the device resets (I think) and I can access the web console from IP 192.168.2.1, but the username and password doesn't work.

Maybe the device doesn't reset after all. Or the username/password has been changed in some firmware upgrade? What should I do to get into management of this switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it!

The web management console doesn't work well on Opera 10 and Chrome. But it works in Firefox 3.6.

So, if you encounter problems try different browsers first.

Comment: I've experience this exact same problem. Doesn't work in Chrome but does in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Real simple solution. I have found that you need to be in private browsing on IE to be able to login with the default credentials. set the login PC's NIC address to the following:

> IP: 192.168.2.10
>   Subnet: 255.255.255.0
>  
>   Default Gateway: 192.168.2.1
>  
>   User: admin
>   Password: blank

I spent some very unnecessary time attempting to log into one that was left at our office. We were trying some port mapping software and nobody could remember the credentials. After hours of searching and finding that I needed to be in private browsing, finally got things working.